# Spring Security query Invalid column index exception but working on Oracle

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am using spring security 4, it appears that the query that I typed doesn't work even though it works properly in PL/SQL.

I want to access to `ROLETYPE` table. The tables are linked with primary & foreign keys like: `UTILISATEURS` have `POSTES` have `ROLES` have `RHNOM` (which is role type `LIB1`)

Here's the query :

```
 authorities-by-username-query="select LIB1 from RHNOM rh, UTILISATEURS u, POSTES p, ROLES r 
            where u.IDPOSTE = p.ID_POSTE and p.ID_ROLE = r.ID_ROLE and r.ID_TYP_ROLE = rh.IDNOM and u.LOGIN  = ?" />
```

error:

```
  Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.InvalidResultSetAccessException: PreparedStatementCallback; invalid ResultSet access for SQL [select LIB1 from RHNOM rh, UTILISATEURS u, POSTES p, ROLES r where u.IDPOSTE = p.ID_POSTE and p.ID_ROLE = r.ID_ROLE and r.ID_TYP_ROLE = rh.IDNOM and u.LOGIN = ?]; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Index de colonne non valide
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:235)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:73)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:660)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:695)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:727)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:737)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:787)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserAuthorities(JdbcDaoImpl.java:236)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:188)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 34 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Index de colonne non valide
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.getString(OracleResultSetImpl.java:1277)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:213)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingResultSet.getString(DelegatingResultSet.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$2.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:240)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl$2.mapRow(JdbcDaoImpl.java:237)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:93)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:60)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:708)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:644)
    ... 41 more
```

Comment: Could you post the code how you set the input value, execute  and then access the result set?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 The code in question is not from the OP, but from the Spring Security library.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel : as you see the OP has its own query to fetch role details to apply and the error with invalid index is related this SQL if i understood. that is why i am asking how  if the input parameter to the query is set which can be one of the cause to Invalid Index error.

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30 the error is with the retrieval of the column not with setting parameters, as shown by the exception stacktrace. The execution of that query is still handled by Spring Security. The problem is - as shown in my answer - that the query of the OP does not match the expectations of Spring Security that the role is in the second column of the query (the query of the OP has only one column).

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel: Understood and thank you. I am more of a oracle sql guy and pretty much new to spring and java than java so thought process is also the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to match all the columns that Spring Security expects, which for `authorities-by-username-query` is `username, authority`, see [`<jdbc-user-service>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.18.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#nsa-jdbc-user-service) and the implementation of retrieval:

> ```java
> protected List<GrantedAuthority> loadUserAuthorities(String username) {
>   return getJdbcTemplate().query(this.authoritiesByUsernameQuery,
>           new String[] { username }, new RowMapper<GrantedAuthority>() {
>               @Override
>               public GrantedAuthority mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum)
>                       throws SQLException {
>                   String roleName = JdbcDaoImpl.this.rolePrefix + rs.getString(2);
>
>                   return new SimpleGrantedAuthority(roleName);
>               }
>           });
> }
> ```

From [`JdbcDaoImpl` in Spring Security 4.2.18](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/4.2.18.RELEASE/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/jdbc/JdbcDaoImpl.java#L247).

As you can see you don't actually need the first column to be username (as it isn't retrieved), but the role (authority) must be the second column, as it is retrieved by index.

In short, you need to change your query to something like:

```sql
select u.LOGIN, LIB1 from ...
```